# Change the cursor shape in operator pending mode

Tags: cursor-motions, terminal, cursor

My cursor in Gvim:

[image: My cursor in Gvim]

My cursor in Gvim after pressing `d`:

[image: My cursor in Gvim after pressing <code>d</code>]

Is there any way I can change the cursor in terminal Vim when in operator pending mode? It doesn't have to look exactly like the screenshots.

This is done by `o:hor50-Cursor` in `guicursor` for Gvim. The only three options I see for Vim are:

```
t_SI    start insert mode (bar cursor shape)        *t_SI* *'t_SI'*
t_SR    start replace mode (underline cursor shape) *t_SR* *'t_SR'*
t_EI    end insert or replace mode (block cursor shape) *t_EI* *'t_EI'*
    |termcap-cursor-shape|
```

But nothing about operator pending mode...

Comment: I don't think it's possible (could use a source code patch ..). What I do is to look at the right-bottom side of Vim window to check for the partially introduced command letters, which show up there (with `showcmd` setting on). I also disable all timeouts and the `esckeys` option (this keeps Vim snappy but allows me to think at what I want to do in op-pending mode for example).

Comment: @VanLaser Yeah, but I like the cursor ;-)

Comment: Hehe, I can understand that :)

Comment: I know C/C++, offer a $ bounty and I may try to implement it in Vim source code, if possible :D

Comment: You could use http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11437/10337 to detect operator pending mode and echo an ansi escape to change the cursor.

Answer (score 3):

This updates the cursor when entering/exiting operator pending mode.

While it is a bit of a hacky solution I don't think it has any performance problems.

```
" This is esentially:
"   exec 'silent !printf "\e[" . a:t . ' q'
"   redraw!
" but without the screen flash
function! s:setCursor(t)
    " Save existing values.
    let [l:title, l:t_ts, l:t_fs, l:titlestring] = [&title, &t_ts, &t_fs, &titlestring]

    try
        let &titleold = ''
        let &t_ts = "\e[0;0"
        let &t_fs = "\e[" . a:t . ' q'
        set title
        set titlestring=H
        redraw!
    finally
        let [&title, &t_ts, &t_fs, &titlestring] = [l:title, l:t_ts, l:t_fs, l:titlestring]
    endtry
endfunction

let s:prevmode = ''
function! DetectPendingMode(timer)
    let l:mode = mode(1)
    if l:mode is# s:prevmode
        return
    endif

    if l:mode is# 'no'
        call <SID>setCursor(4)
    elseif s:prevmode is# 'no'
        call <SID>setCursor(2)
    endif
    let s:prevmode = l:mode
endfunction

call timer_start(250, 'DetectPendingMode', {'repeat': -1})
```

You may need to change the style of the cursor in `SetCursor()` to the one you prefer:

```
0: blinking block.
1: blinking block.
2: steady block.
3: blinking underline.
4: steady underline.
5: blinking bar (xterm).
6: steady bar (xterm).
```