# Is there an autocmd-like event for when operator pending mode is entered?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, autocmd

I'd like to make a plugin to display currently pending keys while in operator-pending mode. As the first part of that, how would I register an autocmd to run when operator-pending mode is entered? I'm using neovim, so I'm totally cool if it only works there.

Comment: Have you seen what `:set showcmd` displays?  What do you intend to show in addition to that?

Comment: Huh! of course it already exists. I've been getting so addicted to vimscript that I didn't think to check. I do want to go further, though - I'd like to preview changes that will be caused by repeating commands, so it'd still be cool to know if there's a way to get that event.

Comment: [`:h autocmd-events`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd%2Devents) gives you all of the available autocommand events, and I don't think there is one for entering operator pending mode. But maybe you could do something with some operator pending mode mappings: [`:h omap-info`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#omap%2Dinfo)

Comment: there is no such event.

Comment: Now there is! (as at 8.2.3430, (sep 12 2022)) `au ModeChanged *:no* {cmd}`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could always poll Vim:

```
let s:m = ''

function! MyHandler(timer)
  let m = mode(1)
  if m != s:m
    if m == 'no'
      echo "operator pending"
    else
      echo "-"
    endif
    let s:m = m
  endif
endfunction
```

Start with:

```
:call timer_start(250, 'MyHandler', {'repeat': -1})
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if still useful. But for future Google searches...

See [h: ModeChanged](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html?#ModeChanged)

Comment: Definitely useful, but some some details (say, an example), would make it even better!