# Do not display letter when waiting for key sequence to complete

Tags: key-bindings

I have the following binding in my `.vimrc` and the default `timeoutlen` of 1000ms.

```
inoremap df <Esc>
inoremap fd <Esc>
```

However, when I type `df` in insert mode slowly but under the threshold, I can see a `d` for a little bit before I type.

Is there a way to increase the amount of time before the `d` is shown at all? (e.g. to somewhere in the 500ms to 1000ms range).

Comment: It might not be possible unless built-in. If I am not mistaken and you want to change the behavior of operator pending mode, you would have to [detect it](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9977/12003) and somehow hide the character under [the cursor](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7014/12003).

Comment: An easier alternative might be to play with `showcmd`. For example you could create autocmds which would toggle `noshowcmd` when you start insert mode and set again `showcmd` when you leave insert mode. That's not exactly what you asked for but that would be an easier workaround.